# Why doesnt anything i add to the html page doesnt showup anything? (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am starting to learn angular just now. I want to create two routes, on clicking one link it should go to that component. If I go http://localhost:4200/dep i get the emp list's html. But on the main page none of it is showing up. Links are also not getting displayed
Here is my app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DepListComponent } from './dep-list/dep-list.component';
import { EmpListComponent } from './emp-list/emp-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DepListComponent,
    EmpListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <h1>navigate</h1>
  <body>
    hdwiqhkac
    <div>
      <a routerLink="dep">
        department
      </a>
      <a routerLink="emp">emp</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</head>
<!-- <AppComponent></AppComponent> -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DepListComponent } from './dep-list/dep-list.component';
import { EmpListComponent } from './emp-list/emp-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"dep", component:DepListComponent},
  {path:"emp", component:EmpListComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

``
```

Comment: You need to prefix with / like /dep and /emp. Also you need to mention for home url path:'' ... If not working, share the console to understand more on the error

Comment: Yeah I did that but its still not showing up. the text i type in is also not showing up. Home url means base tag in index.html? I added that and kept href to"/". Console isnt showing any error

Comment: {path:"", component:DepListComponent},   Try this in app-routing.module.ts

Comment: It just directly shows dept component. I want to navigate b/w the 2 components. But the main problem is none of the things i do on the app.component.hmtl reflect on the page. its not just with buttons even the text b/w body is also not showing up. But is showing up when im using inline html

Comment: Could you angular inject please? Im fairly new to angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app.component.html file should be like

**app.component.html**

```
<header>
      <a routerLink="/dep">
        department
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/emp">emp</a>
    </header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path:"", component:DepListComponent},
  {path:"/dep", component:DepListComponent},
  {path:"/emp", component:EmpListComponent}
];
```

**EDIT 1**

Added working [stackblitz edit link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fs1w1n)

Comment: Its still not showing anything :(